# Calling C# method which returns a Task

Tags: f#

This is some C# code:

```cs
var streamStore = new PostgresStreamStore(new PostgresStreamStoreSettings("Host=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123456;Database=postgres"));
          await streamStore.CreateSchemaIfNotExists();
```

I'm trying to call it from F# like this:

```ml
let db_connection =
  Sql.host "localhost"
  |> Sql.port 5432
  |> Sql.username "postgres"
  |> Sql.password "123456"
  |> Sql.database "postgres"
  |> Sql.str

let store =
  new PostgresStreamStore(PostgresStreamStoreSettings(db_connection))
  
store.CreateSchemaIfNotExists() |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore
```

The code compiles, however the schema in contrast to the C# Version does not a create a schema.
How do I await this `Task` from `store.CreateSchemaIfNotExists`?

I'm getting this error message:

`This expression is a function value, i.e. is missing arguments. Its type is unit -> Tasks.Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C# code, you are using `await`, so this must be inside an `async` method. The corresponding thing in F# would be to use F# asynchronous workflows. Inside those, you can use `let!` which is similar to `await`. This works with computations of type `Async<T>` rather than `Task<T>`. The operation `Async.AwaitTask` turns `Task<T>` into `Async<T>` so that you can access it using `let!`

```
let doSomething () = async { 
  let db_connection =
    Sql.host "localhost"
    // (other configuration omitted)

  let store =
    new PostgresStreamStore(PostgresStreamStoreSettings(db_connection))
  
  let! res = store.CreateSchemaIfNotExists() |> Async.AwaitTask
  return "whatever" }
```

I assume that `CreateSchemaIfNotExists` does not return anything useful, so you can also wait for its completion using `do!`

```
do! store.CreateSchemaIfNotExists() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.Ignore
```

An asynchronous computation then needs to be started using `Async.Start` or `Async.RunSynchronously`, which is akin to starting a task or blocking using `task.RunSynchronously`.

Comment: Thanks, how would I call `doSomething` in the `main` function of a console app now? Now again I can make it compile but no schema gets created.

Comment: Thanks to your blog post (Gotcha #6) I got it running http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/ - thanks again!